# Issue with Retrofit Callbacks

Tags: java, rest, retrofit

I have a retrofit interface that defines a method with a callback, like this one :

```
public interface ApiManagerService {
    @GET("/users/")
    void getUsers(Callback<List<GitHubMember>>);
}
```

`GitHubMember` is just a POJO with 3 fields : id, login and url.  I created a class called ResponseHandler where I can wrap the response from the Callback. Here how it's define :

```
public class ResponseHandler<T> {

private T response;

private RESPONSE_CODE responseCode;

private String detail;

public static enum RESPONSE_CODE {
    OK,     // if request suceed
    APP_ERROR, //technical error for instance network
    TECHNICAL_ERROR // app technical error
}

//getters and setters
```

Here is how I use this class with the getUsers method :

```
public ResponseHandler<List<GitHubMember>> getUsers() {
    ResponseHandler<List<GitHubMember>> handler = new ResponseHandler<List<GitHubMember>>();
    apiManagerService.getUsers(new Callback<List<GitHubMember>> cb) {
        @Override
        public void success(List<GitHubMember> users, Response response) {
            responseHandler.setResponse(users);
            responseHandler.setResponseCode(ResponseHandler.RESPONSE_CODE.OK);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            try {  
            handler.setResponseCode(ResponseHandler.RESPONSE_CODE.APP_ERROR);
            responseHandler.setDetail(error.toString());
            }catch (Exception e){
                handler.setResponseCode(ResponseHandler.RESPONSE_CODE.TECHNICAL_ERROR);
                responseHandler.setDetail(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
   }
   return handler;
```

}

The problem that I have is after executing this method and entering the callback, all the fields in ResponseHandler are null. I am totally sure that the callbacks are executed because I set breakpoints in the callback while debugging.

The apiManagerService object is correctly initialized with the RestAdapter class.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`apiManagerService.getUsers()` only initiates network request and returns. Callback is called after network responded on the background thread. So by the time `return handler` is executed `handler` is still empty. More than that, even if somehow return-statement will be executed after callback, you may not see changes made to the shared variables (fields of handler) by background thread due to Java Memory Model restrictions.

Comment: Any idea how to resolve this problem? I could use a countdownlatch to wait for the callback?

Comment: @Dimitri you can use event bus for this: post result from callback and handle it in subscriber method in Activity or other component. As an example, Otto or EventBus you can use.